# Cygwin undefined reference to adjtime

Tags: c

this is my first time posting a question here so be kind :).

I have a problem porting a linux application to windows (windows 7 64-bit) using cygwin. I had to rewrite some code that is not supported under windows and that doesn´t exist in cygwin (like adjtimex) and I have manage to compile the code but when I am building the application .exe file (by using makefiles) I get a link error:

```
gcc  -Wl,-Map,ppsi.map2 -o ppsi ppsi.o -lrt -lc
ppsi.o: In function `win_time_adjust':
ppsi/time-win/win-time.c:74: undefined reference to `adjtime'
ppsi/time-win/win-time.c:74:(.text+0x1905): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `adjtime'
```

adjtime function is defined in  which is included in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h> /* timex.h not available on windows so we use sys/time.h*/
#include <ppsi/ppsi.h>
```

Here is how a part of the code looks like:

```
static int win_time_adjust(struct pp_instance *ppi, long offset_ns, long freq_ppb){
struct timeval t;
int ret;
t.tv_sec = 0;
t.tv_usec = 0;

if (offset_ns) {
    t.tv_sec = offset_ns / 1000000; 
    t.tv_usec = offset_ns / 1000;  /*microseconds */
}

ret = adjtime(&t, NULL);
pp_diag(ppi, time, 1, "%s: %li %li\n", __func__, offset_ns, freq_ppb);
return ret;
}
```

I have encountered a similar problem before and I solved by linking the missing library when compiling the application. I tired the same here and linked libc (since adjtime is suppose to be there) -lc when compiling but got the same error. I unsure how adjtime is undefined and I wonder if there is some cygwin library I should link instead?

I use cygwin (gcc version 4.9.2) when compiling

Comment: `adjtime()` is BSD, Also Including `<sys/time.h>` is not a good idea.

Comment: From what do you conclude this: "*since adjtime is suppose to be there*"?

Comment: @alk why is <sys/time.h> not a good idea?

Comment: the same for sys/socket I suppose? which socket should I use? socket.h?

Comment: You're asking whether a symbol is defined in a library. You can find that out using `nm`. Symbols that are defined in the library are marked with a capital T (symbols that are only referenced are marked with U etc.). So you can just  `nm /usr/lib/libc.a | grep T | grep adjtime` (or whatever lib you're inspecting) and see what comes up. Once you find the right lib, you can add it to your linkage command.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, `adjtime` is a Linux-ism which likely crawled its way into the BSD world via FreeBSD. It's certainly not documented by any of the C or POSIX standards.

Even those which are documented by the C and POSIX standards often aren't implemented correctly in the Microsoft world, so it wouldn't surprise me that this function doesn't exist.

I'm very interested to hear more about this project of yours. Though a simplistic wrapper of some implementation-defined stuff can be written for the purposes of portability, I can only imagine highly niche usecases, for which there are better alternatives:

- If you need something with a large amount of good, secure entropy to seed your pseudo-random number generator, you should use something provided by a cryptographic library.
- If you want to conduct performance tests, you should learn how to use the profiler rather than rolling your own profiling code. Also, every "performance test" should be conducted as though through the eyes of a scientist observing the very first time; it's generally best not to let tests from previous projects guide optimisation for future projects. Instead, let the profile of the current project guide optimisation for the current project (on the current hardware), and you'll be cheering before you know it!